# Why does g++ -o flag not work when put right after g++?

Tags: g++

My instructor taught us during lecture that it is OK to put -o flag anywhere, for example:

`g++ -o a a.cpp` and `g++ a.cpp -o a` are both fine and they both compile `a.cpp` into an executable file `a`.

However, when I tried: `g++ -Wall –o blackjack blackjack.cpp card.cpp deck.cpp hand.cpp player.cpp rand.cpp` in one of my projects, I received the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find –o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find blackjack: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I tried `g++ -Wall blackjack.cpp card.cpp deck.cpp hand.cpp player.cpp rand.cpp -o blackjack`, it successfully compiled.

Did I somehow do something wrong the first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: The problem is that the first command in the question was copied/pasted from a PDF file, which used a printer's long dash (aka "em dash" or –) instead of a minus sign (or -), for the output file switch "-o".

- The longer dash is visible upon close inspection.
- It's also obvious in the question if you search for it in your web browser (for Firefox, the enable "Match Diacritics" option).

Note that similar problems occur when cutting/pasting text for humans that has quotes or double quotes.  Instead of an ASCII ' or ", one gets extended non-ASCII characters that the shell can't interpret correctly.

---

Edit: I see that you're using WSL.  Can you try the following?  Yes it's a contrived example :-).

File "2.cpp":

```
bool checkEven(int n) {
  return ((n % 2) == 0);
}
```

File "1.cpp":

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool checkEven(int);

int main() {

  int n;

  cout << "Enter a positive  integer: ";
  cin >> n;

  if (checkEven(n))
    cout << n << " is an even number.\n";

}
```

Try to compile it using this syntax:

```
g++ -Wall -o 1 1.cpp 2.cpp
```

----- original text follows -----

Can you provide the specifics of your environment?  It looks like a UNIX system, but which one?  Which version of g++?

I'm using g++ 11.4.0 on Ubuntu 22.04.3.  I tried a small example program without any trouble:

```
g++ -Wall -o main check-prime.cpp main.cpp
```

If you're using a Makefile or other project control file, you may want to examine it for non-printing characters, using eg. `cat -vet theFileName`.  For example: you may have an embedded <CR> character somewhere, if you imported it from a Microsoft environment.

--klode

Comment: I'm using g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0 on wsl in windows11: OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on Windows 10 x86_64, Kernel: 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2

Comment: I tried compiling with `g++ -Wall -o 1 1.cpp 2.cpp`, it returned the error message: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file 1: Is a directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` :-(

Comment: OK this is getting weirder.  Do you have a directory named "1"?  You could also rename the files to something more typical such as...ummm...2.cpp becomes subroutine.cpp and 1.cpp becomes main.cpp.  Then the command will be `g++ -Wall -o main main.cpp subroutine.cpp`.

Comment: OK, things just got really weird. First of all, it turned out that the renaming thing worked, I happened to have a directory named 1, it didn't occur to me... my bad, sorry for that. However, back to my project, when I typed the same command manually, it successfully compiled... Maybe it has something to do with copying and pasting from adobe pdf... Anyway, thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: @csy That's it!  The copy/paste, I mean.  I'm betting that the PDF file uses a long dash instead of a minus sign for the "-o".  Looking more closely at the text in your question, it seems clear.  I'm guessing that when you changed things around to the working case, you typed "-o blackjack" instead of copy/paste from the PDF.  I'll update my answer with a warning about copy/paste.  On a related note, a similar problem arises when copying quote or double-quote characters from human text in eg. PDFs.